# OPLON LBL ADC Rewriting 302 redirect location URLs ending in "/" in 301 without last "/"

Tags: http, url-rewriting

With LBL ADC (http reverse proxy), we need to rewrite the redirect URL coming from services (http header response 302, Location, see example below) when it ends with "/", deleting the final "/". The rewrite must also change the response code from 302 to 301.

eg. original response:
HTTP/1.1 302
Location: /CEC2003/
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 21 Aug 2019 06:49:01 GMT

result I would like to obtain:
HTTP/1.1 301
Location: /CEC2003
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Date: Wed, 21 Aug 2019 06:49:01 GMT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rewrite rule in response.

The condition is checked if there is a "/" as the last character.

The next two actions change the response code and therefore change the location without the final "/".

```
<rewriteHeaderRule enable="true" flow="RESPONSE" 
                   name="changeResponseCodeAndCutLastSlash" 
                   responseCode="302">
<conditions>
    <cond from="ENTITY_RESPONSE" name="Location">
        <regexTag>(.*)/$</regexTag>
    </cond>
</conditions>
<entities>
    <entity enable="true" entityName="FIRST-LINE" action="change">
        <regexTag>^(.*) (.*)(.*)</regexTag>
        <replaceTo>$1 301$3</replaceTo>
    </entity>
    <entity enable="true" entityName="Location" action="change">
        <regexTag>(.*)/$</regexTag>
        <replaceTo>$1</replaceTo>
    </entity>
</entities>
```